# What app/feature/software is this microphone image from?

Tags: software, microphone

What is this microphone image from? It appeared on my friend's MacBook and she can't figure it out.

[image: screen capture of a round window with a microphone icon inside]

Answer (score 7):

This is the Mac OS X built in voice input mechanism.

[image]

To turn it off, visit preferences - it's possible to turn it on via a keyboard shortcut which may explain it's random appearance.

[image]

> **Speech Recognition**
>
> Speakable Items, built into OS X and located in the Speech pane of
>   System Preferences, lets you control the computer using your voice
>   instead of the keyboard. And you don’t have to train your Mac to use
>   it. You can use Speakable Items to navigate menus and enter keyboard
>   shortcuts; speak checkbox names, radio button names, list items, and
>   button names; and open, close, control, and switch among applications

This article from [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/215764/hack-attack-make-your-macs-speech-recognition-work-for-you) explains how to use the feature is you are interested in learning more.

Comment: You are so very great. Thank you so much for your help on this.
I was close with my investigation. Nothing was listed in the Force Quit, so from that I deduced that it was from some built-in feature. I then figured it would be in Universal Access, kinda the opposite of VoiceOver, but looked and looked and couldn't find anything with a microphone in Universal Access. I guess I should have looked further down on the System Preferences list to Speech, like you said. Thanks SO much!

Comment: I would hazard to guess 9 out of 10 people that see this icon for the first time discover speech recognition when the Chess app runs...

Comment: Interesting. I have never used the Chess app, so I had never seen the mic before. Man you guys are helpful here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your friend navigates to the *Speech* pane of her *System Preferences* she'll see that [*Speakable Items*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speakable_items) is enabled. Speakable Items is a limited form of voice recognition that allows you to issue commands to your Macintosh vocally. The microphone device you see indicates that the system is listening and, if I remember correctly, can also be used to toggle the listening state of the Mac.

Comment: You are so great. Thank you so much for your help on this.
I was close with my investigation. Nothing was listed in the Force Quit, so from that I deduced that it was from some built-in feature. I then figured it would be in Universal Access, kinda the opposite of VoiceOver, but looked and looked and couldn't find anything with a microphone in Universal Access. I guess I should have looked further down on the System Preferences list to Speech, like you said. Thanks SO much!